# Group command with a pipeline in Bash

Tags: bash

In the book "The Linux Command Line" the author presents an example of sorting an array:

```
arr=(f e d c b a)
arr_sorted=($(for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo $i; done | sort))
```

The output from the `for` loop (which prints all subsequent array values with `echo`) is pipelined to `sort`.

On the other hand, in another chapter the author presents a similar example but exploiting a Bash "group command" which is denoted by surrounding braces `{ }` (I minimized his script preserving the idea):

```
declare -A arr  # an associative array
arr["key0"]=val0
arr["key2"]=val2
arr["key1"]=val1
{ for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$i" "${arr["$i"]}"
done } | sort
```

The author's point is: *"(...) Also note that the entire loop is enclosed in braces thus forming a group command. This permits the entire output of the loop to be piped into the sort command."*

However I ran this script (both the book's original and the minimized) both with and without "group command" braces and they all worked perfectly the same - the output is equivalent.

So why the author insists on using a group command in the above case although it works perfectly OK without it and even he himself showed a similar working version (with `arr_sorted`) in the previous chapter? Maybe I'm missing something else here.

Comment: `for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo $i; done` - just `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"`. Do you want an answer like - "there is no difference between putting it in command group and not"?

Comment: My guess is poor editing; the command group is absolutely unnecessary here, as it only wraps a single (compound) command.

Comment: @chepner it seems like authors' overlook then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command group would be useful if you wanted to combine the output of two or more separate commands. For example,

```
{
   for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
       printf "%s: %s\n" "$i" "${arr["$i"]}"
   done

   while IFS=, read -r a b; do
       printf "%s: %s\n" "$a" "$b"
   done < some_file.txt
} | sort
```

But as you noticed, a `for` loop is already a single command, so there's no point in wrapping it inside another compound command to collect its output for a pipe.

---

A command group is especially nice for avoiding repeated redirections, which requires repeated opening and closing of files. Code like

```
echo ... > some_file.txt
echo ... >> some_file.txt
echo ... >> some_file.txt
echo ... >> some_file.txt
echo ... >> some_file.txt
```

can be replaced with

```
{
  echo ...
  echo ...
  echo ...
  echo ...
  echo ...
} > some_file.txt
```

which opens `some_file.txt` *once*, not five times.

Comment: And already I know it was worth asking - the example with several loops is useful and nicely supplementing the topic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between putting a single command in `{` `}` braces or not.

The:

```
{ for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$i" "${arr["$i"]}"
done } | sort
```

is equivalent to:

```
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$i" "${arr["$i"]}"
done | sort
```

Ex.:

```
{ { { { { echo a; }; }; }; }; }
```

is just `echo a`

Comment: You didn't have put it in the answer **literally**, I believed you from the comment ;) Anyway, thanks!